# Is Finn's sword able to interact with him?

Tags: adventure-time

> Finn's sword first appears in the Breezy episode, being held by the image of princess Bubblegum during the last song (before Finn gets his arm back). Finn literally gets his arm back in the *is that you* episode after resurrecting Prismo Finn interacts with the other Finn from another dimension and turns him into his sword. In the *dentist* episode he says something to his sword.

Did he really talk to the Finn from the sword, or just imagined him answering?